# When to use Foundation/Bootstrap or custom css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

So this has been a topic of debate between me and another coder. We are using foundation for a project and he really likes following the system they provide. I like to venture out when it doesn't fit exactly.

An example was this was when I was doing the login form and I wanted a singular sized view that looks the same on every view. I created a login form with a solid width and centered with margins. He comes back to the code and puts it in foundation with large/medium/small columns. The justification was that they know how to handle responsiveness better than us. I just wanted stack overflow's opinion on this one.

When is it right to use a css framework and when should you go outside of it?

Comment: if you want more than a "it depends" as an answer you should be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I guess on big projects, where you'd like to use each an every feature that a css framework provides, you should go for it. Whereas in small websites, using Bootstrap/Foundation would be a slow-down factor.

Otherwise if you are confident with building a responsive framework yourself, you should go ahead. But, if you feel you aren't take help from others in the form of css frameworks.

This question is way too broad and there can be many possible answers. The above is just my point of view.

Comment: Thanks for the input. What I was really getting at is when you are already using a framework, when should you use and and when should you ignore it. The frameworks provide a lot of tools, but sometimes it doesn't do exactly what I want. You can either side with the framework or roll your own css. It is something that regularly comes up during development for my team.

Comment: Ah! In that case you should try to stick with the framework as much as possible and use custom inline styling wherever required. Or if required in many places, make a class that overrides the default features. Again, this is just my point of view.

Comment: That makes sense and is pretty much what we have been doing. And I it really is up to the coder to decide how they want to do things. I do find though that these decisions really changes the flow of your app  though. It's one of those grand scheme coding concepts that should be discussed in my opinion.

Comment: Yes! And one more thing. It is better to maintain a particular way throughout your project. Changing your way in between can really screw things up.

Comment: I agree, this seems to be the only thing that is necessary with whatever route you go.

Comment: So did you find what you wanted through this question?

Comment: I don't think there was a true 'answer' to this question. If anything you confirmed the fact that yes there is no best method. I come to this conclusion regularly in programming. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you already have experience with one framework, unless you're doing it for research stick with it.
Otherwise you could check this [comparison](http://www.zingdesign.com/bootstrap-3-vs-foundation-4-feature-lineup/).

Also if you're using a web framework like Rails, Spring MVC, etc, check the integration status between the both frameworks.

Another point you should care is the community, and in my humble opinion bootstrap wins (as my personal perception).